# What's best? A model with nested random effects supported by AIC, but that validates poorly; or one with a simpler random part that validates better?

Tags: r, mixed-model, lme4-nlme, random-effects-model, aic

I am trying to fit a linear model to understand the factors that influence (marine) plant carbon stocks at a global level. The potential predictors of carbon stocks that I want to include in the model as fixed effects are: the name of the plant `Species`, the `depth` at which the stock was measured (2 levels: shallow and deep), the environmental setting (`FIN_TYP_names`) where the stocks were measured (7 levels: deltas, tidal systems, arid coasts, etc) and the climatic zone (tropical, temperate, polar).

Carbon stocks were obtained from published and unpublished papers. Carbon stocks coming from the same paper cannot be considered independent, and therefore, I consider the title of the paper where the carbon stock was published as a random effect (I call this random effect `Source`). There might be another source of non-independence in this model, which is the fact that stocks were measured in sediment cores at 2 points (shallow and deep). Therefore, these 2 observations from the same core, cannot be considered independent either. Since each core comes from only one publication, I think `CoreID_unique`should be nested within `Source`.

Note that we are also dealing with variance heterogeneity at the `Species` level, which I model as weights in `lme` (see below).

Let's check the AIC for different models only changing the random part of the model:

```
m0.w.lme <- lme(log(cstocks) ~ Species*depth + FIN_TYP_names + Lat_Zone, 
                random = ~1|Source,
                weights = varIdent(form = ~1|Species), 
                control = lmeControl(maxIter = 1000, msMaxIter = 1000),
                data = cstocks_data_both_depths)
    
m0.w.lme1 <- lme(log(cstocks) ~ Species*depth + FIN_TYP_names + Lat_Zone, 
                random = ~1|CoreID_unique,
                weights = varIdent(form = ~1|Species), 
                control = lmeControl(maxIter = 1000, msMaxIter = 1000),
                data = cstocks_data_both_depths)
    
m0.w.lme2 <- lme(log(cstocks) ~ Species*depth + FIN_TYP_names + Lat_Zone, 
                random = ~1|Source/CoreID_unique,
                weights = varIdent(form = ~1|Species), 
                control = lmeControl(maxIter = 1000, msMaxIter = 1000),
                data = cstocks_data_both_depths)
    
m0.w.lme3 <- lme(log(cstocks) ~ Species*depth + FIN_TYP_names + Lat_Zone, 
                 random = ~1 + CoreID_unique|Source,
                 weights = varIdent(form = ~1|Species), 
                 control = lmeControl(maxIter = 1000, msMaxIter = 1000),
                 data = cstocks_data_both_depths)

AIC(m0.w.lme, m0.w.lme1, m0.w.lme2, m0.w.lme3)
#           df      AIC
# m0.w.lme  51 662.2859
# m0.w.lme1 51 611.6578
# m0.w.lme2 52 596.2468  This is the best model. The one with nested random effects.
# m0.w.lme3 53 664.3825
```

The best selected model according to AIC and also LR tests (comparing models with `anova()`) is, therefore, the following:

```
m0.w.lme2 <- lme(log(cstocks) ~ Species*depth + FIN_TYP_names + Lat_Zone, 
                random = ~1|Source/CoreID_unique,
                weights = varIdent(form = ~1|Species), 
                control = lmeControl(maxIter = 1000, msMaxIter = 1000),
                data = cstocks_data_both_depths)
```

However, as soon as the random effect `CoreID_unique`is included in any model, model residuals go crazy in qqplots.

Compare the validation of the model `m0.w.lme` (only including `Source` as a random intercept) with the validation of the model `m0.w.lme2` (including `Source/CoreID_unique` random structure):

[image]

**So, what do you think is better?** The model with only `Source`as a random intercept, which has a higher AIC but validates OK (not perfect, but reasonably well); or the model with the nested random effects `Source/CoreID_unique`, which is better according to AIC but has a much worse validation?

---

Just seen this answer to a similar question:
[Adding an observation level random term messes up residuals vs fitted plot. Why?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/351352/adding-an-observation-level-random-term-messes-up-residuals-vs-fitted-plot-why)

Which made me check some more diagnostic/validation plots. See for example this plot of fitted values vs. the response, which clearly shows that the model with nested random effects is better at fitting the response variable.

[image]

Thus, all in all, it's obvious that adding `CoreID_unique` as a nested random effect improves the description of the response variable, in spite of a bit of overdispersion in the qqplots, which now I find less worrisome.

**Any other ideas, comments? Thanks for any input!**